# Triggerring HeatMap Plugin using Python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to access heatmap plugin from Raster -> HeatMap -> HeatMap using PyQGIS.If my custom button is clicked, the heatmap plugin dialog box should opens.I know the heatmap is a c++ plugin.Is it possible to trigger the heatmap plugin using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rasterMenu = qgis.utils.iface.rasterMenu()
for rasterMenuItem in rasterMenu.actions():
 if 'Heatmap' in rasterMenuItem.text():
  heatmapMenu = rasterMenuItem

  for heatmapMenuItem in heatmapMenu.menu().actions():
    print heatmapMenuItem
    if 'Heatmap' in heatmapMenuItem.text():
        heatmapMenuItem.trigger()
```